# How to adjust the learning rate after N number of epochs?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using Hugginface's Trainer.
How to adjust the learning rate after N number of epochs?
For example, I have an initial learning rate set to `lr=2e-6`, and I would like to change the learning rate to `lr=1e-6` after the first epoch and stay on it the rest of the training.

I tried this so far:

```
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(),
              lr = 2e-5,
              eps = 1e-8
            )

epochs = 5
batch_number = len(small_train_dataset) / 8
total_steps = batch_number * epochs


scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, 
                                            num_warmup_steps = 0,
                                            num_training_steps = total_steps,
                                            last_epoch=-1
                                            )
```

I know that there is https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR but here it drops learning rate every epoch but that is not what i want to do. I want it to drop after 1 epoch and then stay on it rest of the training process.

Answer (score 1):

You could train in two steps,
first, train with desired initial learning rate then create a second optimizer with the final learning rate. It is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use scheduler like this:

```
scheduler = get_constant_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps = N / batch_size)
```

where `N` is number of epochs after which you want to use the constant lr.

This will increase your `lr` from `0` to `initial_lr` specified in your optimizer in `num_warmup_steps`, after which it becomes constant.

> I have an initial learning rate set to lr=2e-6, and I would like to
> change the learning rate to lr=1e-6 after the first epoch

Looks like transformer schedulers don't give any option to start the warmup from a pre-specified learning rate (e.g. `2e-6` in your case). You could start the learning rate from `0` instead as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own learning rate scheduler with [Lambda_LR](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR) from pytorch:

```py
import torch

initial_lr = 2e-6

num_update_steps_per_epoch = len(train_dataloader)  #that is a pytorch dataloader

#initial_lr * 0.5 = 1e-6
lambda_lr = lambda current_step: 0.5 if current_step<=num_update_steps_per_epoch else 1

lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(
   optimizer=optimizer,
   lr_lambda = lambda_lr
)
```